# Custom Woocommerce Search Result Page should look like shop layout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am creating custom search feature in a theme. I have created a form on the homepage and with action set to a custom php search page. Form looks like this somewhat. I AM GETTING `Class WP_Query not` found Error. How to make it work?


The woo-search.php looks like this. I am using this as a template file. forms action attribute links to the page which has this template applied

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 * Template Name: Search Page
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

  get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php 
            global $wp_query;
global $wpdb;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // echo "Submitted <br>";


    $product_kinds = $_POST['product-kinds'];
    echo $product_kinds;

    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => '2-wheeler-batteries'));
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();


}else{
    echo "Get Away";
}
         ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For demonstration purpose the query inside wp_query is static. I want to display the search result just like the shop page looks like, I mean with product image, then title, then price and add to cart button. With above code I will need to fetch all seperately and code it to look like the shop page. How do I fetch Woocommerce layout in this search results. What changes should I make in the while loop.[image]